# How to delete primary key constraint after table is droppped in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key, create-table

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE SHIP_CABINS
(
    SHIP_CABIN_ID NUMBER,
    SHIP_ID NUMBER,
    GUESTS NUMBER(3),
    SQ_FT NUMBER(6),
    CONSTRAINT SHIP_CABIN_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (SHIP_CABIN_ID)
);
```

I then dropped the table like this:

```
DROP TABLE SHIP_CABINS;
```

Because I didn't use `CASCADE CONSTRAINTS`, the primary key constraint SHIP_CABIN_ID_PK still exists after the table is dropped.

I don't know how to remove the primary key after the table no longer exists. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a misconception here. Dropping a table *does* removes its primary key constraint.

`cascade constraints` is a different beast, that is meant to automatically remove foreign key constraints that reference the table being dropped. If there are such constraint, the database prevents you from dropping the table, unless you specify that option.

Consider the [following demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=770df97cf884a45be8ef48c46d8a14f2):

```
-- create the table
create table ship_cabins (
    ship_cabin_id number,
    ship_id number,
    guests number(3),
    sq_ft number(6),
    constraint ship_cabin_id_pk primary key (ship_cabin_id)
);

-- check the table constraints
select constraint_name, constraint_type from user_constraints where table_name = 'SHIP_CABINS';

CONSTRAINT_NAME  | CONSTRAINT_TYPE
:--------------- | :--------------
SHIP_CABIN_ID_PK | P              

-- drop the table
drop table ship_cabins;

-- the PK constraint is gone
select constraint_name, constraint_type from user_constraints where table_name = 'SHIP_CABINS';

CONSTRAINT_NAME | CONSTRAINT_TYPE
:-------------- | :--------------
```

Comment: But when I tried to create another table with the same primary key name, Oracle won't allow me and told me the constraint name already exsits. I tried to run SELECT * FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS, I can see the SHIP_CABIN_ID_PK is still there.

Comment: @ZZZ Are you logged in with the correct user? If the table exists in two schemas and you deleted it from one and then logged into the other one then it would appear to still be there.